# flatting Observable of Array to Observable of items

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to flat an `Observable<Array<ISource>>` to an `Observable<ISource>`.

In order to get it:

```
this.sources$ = this.store$
    .select(fromRoot.getSourceEntities)
    .map(sourceEntities => {
      return sourceEntities
        .filter((source:ISource) => source.id != null)
        .map((source:ISource) => { return <ISource>{id: source.id}; });
    })
    .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$);
```

I'm getting this compiler error messsage:

```
Type 'Observable<ISource[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ISource>'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`this.sources$` is type of `ISource` but you are returning `ISource[]` to it thats why it is giving error change the decleration of `this.sources$` like below your `sourceEntries` is a array and it is filter and return a bunch of ISource objects.

```
sources$: ISource[];
```